# How to load values from xml and use them in all pages?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

so, I am working on a little WPF Application, mainly for learning.
I have multiple pages in my WPF App with sliders, checkboxes etc on each page. Now, what I want to do is to save all the values from the controlelements in one xml file. When I restart the Application, it should read that xml and use the values stored inside.

I know how to do it in a simple windowsforms, but I cant get it working with WPF..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow :D

**Here's a simple example using [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx):**

I will make a small window that shows some settings.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Create XML sample data
            var settings = new MySettings {Setting1 = "hello !", Setting2 = "hi !"};
            var serializer1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof (MySettings));
            string xml;
            using (TextWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                serializer1.Serialize(textWriter, settings);
                xml = textWriter.ToString();
            }

            // Deserialize that sample data to an object
            var serializer2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof (MySettings));
            MySettings deserialize;
            using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                deserialize = serializer2.Deserialize(stringReader) as MySettings;
            }

            // Use deserialized data as our context
            if (deserialize != null)
            {
                DataContext = deserialize;
            }
        }
    }

    public class MySettings
    {
        public string Setting1 { get; set; }
        public string Setting2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

XAML part (most interesting to you IMO):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance wpfApplication1:MySettings}">
            <TextBlock>Setting 1</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Setting1}" />
            <TextBlock>Setting 2</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Setting2}" />

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

So from this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MySettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Setting1>hello !</Setting1>
  <Setting2>hi !</Setting2>
</MySettings>
```

We end up to this:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, thats fine. But now lets say i have another window MainWindow2. In that window I want to load the values, e.g. "hello !", change it to "good bye" and then have a button in MainWindow2 to save it so MainWindow shows "good bye". thats the key problem i got atm, I dont know how to "send it back" from MainWindow2 to the xml

Comment: To do this, create a static 'MySettings' property in your App.xaml.cs, make sure it implements INotifyPropertyChanged then on both of your windows you will bind to this property. Any changes you make on either window will be propagated.